# Can Banana Pi M3 act as a Bluetooth beacon

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, banana-pi

I am planning to engage in a DIY project which needs a programmable android beacon. The beacon's task would include connecting to android devices (mostly mobile phones) and calling web services etc.

After some research I think the Banana Pi M3 would be a great choice. Everything fits perfectly except the one doubt i'm still unable to find an answer to - **is the Banana Pi M3 running on android 5.1 capable of advertising a custom UUID like the raspberry Pi?** simply, is the BPI M3 capable of Bluetooth advertising?

If the answer is yes I will go ahead and purchase the product or else please suggest a suitable programmable android beacon.

Comment: Hopefully somebody will respond who has tried it.  There is not really any other way to know.

Comment: Is Android capable of working as a Beacon?

Comment: Yes it is. Starting from API 21.